# zero number of collection count mongodb using db.stats but correct pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I use PyMongo to get the number of collections in MongoDB. I added dew collections to the database using PyMongo. I got the correct number. But, if I use `db.stats()` in Mongo shell, to get the number of collections in the database, I got Zero number of collections. What is the problem?

Comment: connected to the wrong db?

Comment: no I am sure about the db connection

Comment: Did you execute `use <dbname>` prior to executing `db.stats()`?

Comment: Yes I did, I got the name of the database at out put of db.stats() with the zero values of collection, size, ...

Comment: Please provide complete code snippets including database URIs etc. for both inquiries (you can redact passwords).